# Story from 9th grade literature class about mission to planet where explorers are killed by poisonous spiders

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is narrated by a girl who is the lone survivor and can telepathically hear the thoughts of the spiders.

Comment: Welcome! Do you remember anything else about this book, like when you read it? Here's a guide that can help you remember more details: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872

Comment: Thanks for the response! After reading the guide, I see that I've left out some details that I remember.
1. I read it in 1987. Not sure when it was published though.
2. The narrator is a girl who is chosen for the mission to study possible animal-life on the planet.
3. She is part of the second mission. There was a first mission that was never heard from again.
4. The first and second crew apparently find gold while exploring the planet and abandon their mission tasks due to greed. With the exception of the narrator, they are all killed by poisonous spiders or spider-like creatures.